# Spring can't access database data if single object is queried

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to query a single object from the database and whenever I execute the app it throws a null pointer exception, but when I query the whole table and place it on a list, I am getting all the result so there is no problem with the configurations for I can access the database. here is the part of the code that throws error:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.erp.entity.User;

@Repository
public class UsersDAOImpl implements UsersDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
@Transactional
public User getUser(String username) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    String hql = "FROM User WHERE username = '" + username + "'";

    Query<User> query =  currentSession.createQuery(hql, User.class);

    User user = (User) query.getSingleResult();

    return user;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<User> getUsers() {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query<User> query = currentSession.createQuery("FROM User", User.class);

    List<User> users = query.getResultList();

    return users;
}

}
```

Here is the thrown error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ERPapplication] threw exception[Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException at com.erp.dao.UsersDAOImpl.getUser(UsersDAOImpl.java:23) at com.erp.controller.LoginController.greeting(LoginController.java:39)
```

Here is the controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/erp")
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private UsersDAO usersDAO;

@RequestMapping("/list")
public String listUsers(Model model) {
    List<User> users = usersDAO.getUsers();

    model.addAttribute("users", users);

    return "list-users";
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model) {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String greeting(Model model) {
    UsersDAO usersDAO = new UsersDAOImpl();

    if(usersDAO.getUser("username").getUsername().equals("username")) {
        return "greeting";
    } else {
        return "list-users";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 23?

Comment: you are querying the user by it's "username" shouldn't you be doing that by the User id?

Comment: Line 23 is Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() within the getUser() method.

Comment: I tried this but the error is still there: Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   
  String hql = "FROM User WHERE username = '" + username + "'";
  
  Query<User> query =  currentSession.createQuery(hql, User.class);
  
  User user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
  
  return user;

Comment: You have a null pointer exception - that's on you, not Spring.  The exception is in your Controller class, not the one you posted.  Did you not read the exception message?

Comment: I'll add my controller class in the original post.

Comment: @duffymo, I posted my controller class, can you check? the getUser method is supposed to return a User object, then I try to compare the username of the extracted user object from the database with a username that I supplied to simplify the checking before letting the real users supply the username, where do you think am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, I'm not going to check.  The exception tells you the line number at which you get the NPE.  Look in your IDE.  If that's not clear enough, run a session in your debugger.

Comment: I got it, I completely forgot to run a session in debugger, the problem is that I am not using the injected object which is UsersDAO, I am instantiating a completely new object of UsersDAOImpl within the greeting() method in the controller, that is why it is throwing a null pointer exception.. thanks very big!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `UsersDAO usersDAO = new UsersDAOImpl();` in your `Controller` class. Thats a new instance, not the singleton created with Spring component scan. Use the `Autowire`d one, `UsersDao usersDao` to call the method. I think you didn't notice that!